# Pi camera no preview & omxplayer fail to play

Tags: pi-2

1.I have interfaced Pi-camera version1.3 with raspberry pi. 
Problem is I am not able to get any preview with this.

2. Following libs are added:
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get  install python-picamera
   sudo apt-get install python3-piamera
   sudo apt-get install omxplayer
3. On terminal when I typed:$raspistill -p
   Error generated: invalid command line option (-p)
4. I am successfully able to get image with following command:
   $raspistill -o image.png
5. Though when I tried to run in python code, I don't get any preview. Although a video file is formed. But while video is recording I dont screen anything on streaming of video i.e no preview.

       `import picamera
       import time`

   ```
   camera = picamera.Picamera()
   camera.capture('img.png')

   camera.start_preview()
   camera.start_recording('vid.h264')
   time.sleep(10)
   camera.stop_recording()
   ```
6. After that a video file of arounf 10MB is created on disk. But when I try to run it with omxplayer, only below message appears on terminal, no video file running
   $omxplayer videofile.h264

Video codec omx-h264 width 1024 height 768 profile 100 fps 25.000000
Subtitle count: 0, state: off, index: 1, delay: 000000V:PortSettingsChanged: 1024x768@25.00 interlace:0 deinterlace:0 anaglyph:0 par:1
.00 layer:0 alpha:255
have a nice day;)

7. however I have copied file to window platform & run it in vlc media player.
   It runned successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, I have found the cause. Actually I was running it on window Desktop via VNC. However when I viewed it by monitor connected to HDMi output of Pi, it worked.
Preview/video don't come oplay via vnc. Connect HDMi out for this.